# double free or corruption (!prev) occured using the vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

When I was writing the Iteration Merge Sort Code using the vector in C++,I met the error double free or corruption (!prev) when the vector size n is between 17 and 30;When n is smaller than 17 or larger than 30,there is no error.And the code Implemented sorting function.But I didn't use free or delete,why this error will occur?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
// v1[left...middle] and v1[middle+1...right] are Ordered,merge them to v2;
void Merge(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = left, k = middle + 1;
    while (i <= middle && k <= right)
    {
        if (v1[i] <= v1[k])
            v2[j] = v1[i++];
        else
            v2[j] = v1[k++];
        ++j;
    }
    while (i <= middle)
    {
        v2[j++] = v1[i++];
    }
    while (k <= right)
    {
        v2[j++] = v1[k++];
    }
}

// Merge adjacent subsequences of length interval in v1 into v2
void MergePass(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2, int interval)
{
    int i = 0, k = v1.size() - 2 * interval + 1;
    while (i < k)
    {
        Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, i + 2 * interval - 1);
        i += 2 * interval;
    }

    /*for (i = 0; i < v1.size() - 2 * interval + 1; i += 2 * interval)
    {
        Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, i + 2 * interval - 1);
    }*/
    if (i < v1.size() - interval)
        Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, v1.size() - 1);
    else
    {
        for (; i < v1.size(); i++)
        {
            v2[i] = v1[i];
        }
    }
}
void MergeSort(vector<int> &v)
{
    int k= v.size();
    vector<int> v1(k);
    int i = 1;
    while (i < v.size())
    {
        MergePass(v, v1, i);
        i *= 2;
        MergePass(v1, v, i);
        i *= 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    vector<int> v;
    int n;
    cout << "input the size:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        v.push_back(rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
    MergeSort(v);
```

Comment: *When n is smaller than 17 or larger than 30,there is no error* -- There is always an error.  There is nothing magical about the number 17 or 30.

Comment: You do free/delete, except it is hidden for you in vector's destructor. This error most likely means that you've went outside of vector's range somewhere. Your `<=` conditions on indexes (in loops) look suspicious.

Comment: `v2[j++] = v1[i++];` -- 1) Replace this with `v2.at(j++) = v1.at(i++);`.  2) Replace: `v2[j++] = v1[k++];` with `v2.at(j++) = v1.at(k++);`  3) Don't use random data.  Use a known set of data that causes the error.  By using random data, you are moving the target around each time you run the program.  Those calls to `at()` will tell you if you are going out-of-bounds.

Comment: In `MergeSort` there's a loop `while(i < v.size()){ MergePass(...); i*=2; MergePass(...); i*=2;}`, note that in the second call to `MergePass`, `i` could be outside the bound.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
In `MergePass` function

```
if (i < v1.size() - interval)
        Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, v1.size() - 1);
```

the size() returns std::size_t,when v1.size()<interval,v1.size()<interval will get a very large positive integer,`Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, v1.size() - 1)` will still be run.So there is out-of-bounds.I change it to

```
if (i < (int)v1.size() - interval)
        Merge(v1, v2, i, i + interval - 1, v1.size() - 1);
```

Thanks to @PaulMcKenzie and everyone helped me.